# CDI - Injection not resolved

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I've this class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigurationResources {...}
```

By other hand, I'm using `ConfigurationResources` inside a `ClientAuthzService`:

```
public class ClientAuthzService {
    @Inject protected ConfigurationResources configurationResources;
    //...
}
```

I'm injecting it when a request an endpoint is reached to my JAXRS interface:

```
public class ClientAuthzEndpoint implements IClientAuthzEndpoint {
    @Inject private ClientAuthzService clientAuthzService;
    //...
}
```

and `IClientAuthzEndpoint`:

```
@Path(value = "/client")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface IClientAuthzEndpoint {
```

However, `ConfigurationResources` is not injected inside a `ClientAuthService`:

```
public ClientAuthzService()
    {
        this.mongoUserRepository = new UserMongoRepository(
            new MongoContextSource(
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbServer(),
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbPort(),
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbDatabase(),
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbUsername(),
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbPassword(),
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbAuthenticationDatabase()
            )
        );
```

I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` due to `configurationResources` is `null`!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access injected objects from a constructor. CDI needs to be able to construct the object before injecting stuff into it.

You can perform any initialisation that you need in an `@PostConstruct` annotated method:

```
public class ClientAuthzService {

    @Inject
    private ConfigurationResources configurationResources;

    private UserMongoRepository mongoUserRepository;

    public ClientAuthzService() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    void initialise() {
        this.mongoUserRepository = new UserMongoRepository(
            new MongoContextSource(
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbServer(),
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbPort(),
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbDatabase(),
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbUsername(),
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbPassword(),
                this.configurationResources.getMongodbAuthenticationDatabase()
            )
        );
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `ClientAuthzEndpoint`
is a valid bean(is inside CDI context).
try to add above your class:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
```

In other words. Make sure that all classes where you are using `@Inject` is valid bean thus has proper annotation.